# Calculation in Calculated Column varying based on null values?

Tags: 2013, calculated-column, survey

Here's one I've never dealt with before:
I have calculated columns (in a SharePoint 2013 survey) that calculate values based on particular survey questions.  One of those values, however, is an "N/A" value (currently set to the number zero). What I'm trying to do is this - I need to create an average of the NON-N/A answers.  For example - I have 4 survey questions from which I extrapolate an average.  If one of the of the answers is N/A, I need to get the average of the other three only.  What should my calculated column formula be?  I've never fathomed this one before.

I know that in Excel, we could use a function like this:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A2:D2, ">0")
```

But SharePoint doesn't recognize AVERAGEIF.  Does this example help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for three fields:

```
=(q1+q2+q3)/(IF(q1=0,0,1)+IF(q2=0,0,1)+IF(q3=0,0,1))
```

So, add the values for the three fields, and then divide by the number of fields with a non-zero value.

You may need to add another if statement around the rest to avoid a divide by zero error.

Comment: So, according to the logic of what you've shown above, calculation for five fields would look like     =(q1+q2+q3+q4+q5)/(IF(q1=0,0,0,0,1)+IF(q2=0,0,0,0,1)+IF(q3=0,0,0,0,1)+IF(q4=0,0,0,0,1)+IF(q5=0,0,0,0,1)   ?

Comment: The If syntax is if(condition, true value, false value). So, If(q5=0,0,1). So, given values of 1,2,3,4,0, the bottom set of if statements will result in: 1+1+1+1+0, and therefore will be 10/4

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks, Mike.

Comment: CORRECTION @Mike2500 - This isn't working.  When I have 4 fields, and two of them are 9, with the other two as 0, This calculation still gives me 4.50 instead of 9 as an average.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you paste in the formula you have for the four fields? The end result should be (9+9+0+0)/(1+1+0+0)  = 18/2 = 9

Comment: =([Item 158 value] + [Item 160 value] + [Item 174 value] + [Item 163 value] + [Item 175 value])/(IF([Item 158 value]=0,0,1)+IF([Item 160 value]=0,0,1)+IF([Item 174 value]=0,0,1)+
IF([Item 163 value]=0,0,1)+IF([Item 175 value]=0,0,1))

Comment: You mentioned 4 fields/values, but your formula has five fields. What are the values of all 5 fields?

Comment: This one has 5.  The values I'm using are 5,0,0,0,5.

Comment: And that gives an average of 5?

Comment: Correction - my values are 5,5,5,0,0.  It's giving me an average of 3.

Comment: Perhaps your fields are set up as single lines of text, rather than as numbers? If possible, you should switch your field type to match what they are: numbers. Otherwise, you'll need to modify the if statements to look for "0", instead of 0:  IF(q1="0",0,1))

Comment: That's a good point that I hadn't considered.  Let me try that.

Comment: Mike, it's working like a charm for the most part.  Some areas are giving me the divide by zero error that you mentioned earlier, though.  What should I add to fix this?

Comment: wrap the entire bottom section in another if statement, if the result is zero, output something else as desired.

Comment: Everything to the right of the slash (divisor), you mean? If the result is zero, I simply want the output to be zero.